# Using OpenGraph to pull content onto my site?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

So a company I'm working with gets mentioned in the media from time to time (BBC & other big news sites).

Is anyone aware of fees / licenses we will need to use the content that BBC etc provides using OpenGraph and post that content on our site?
So essentially we want a little card on our site with the page title, OG image, URL and possibly the description, when the user clicks this it will open the original page/link on the original source site.

I can't see too much info out there other than sharing on facebook, not using OpenGraph on our site.

Can anyone share some knowledge? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you want to retrieve posts on the BBC site, scrape the information and show in your own site, right?

Does the site of BBC, and possible others, provide a feed where you can subscribe to? In that case, you could monitor that feed for any mentions of your company.

Alternatively, you can use one of Facebook's partners that use the [Keyword Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights#partners). There you can set up monitoring for your company name and integrate with their API.

Comment: Pretty much yeah, we only want to show their OG image, title, description (possibly) and URL. So it's content that they provide using OpenGraph which is used by social networks.

So we just want to show where we are mentioned, and link the user to the full article on the author site. 

I'll check out the Keyword Insights API thanks!